# Is cpio command in Linux is stand-alone?

Tags: linux, cpio

I am working on ubuntu 20.04 OS setup, everything working fine on my system. But when I share package to someone we are facing some issue with cpio.

So thought to share cpio command as standalone executable.

Does it have all necessary system libraries to work with from 16.04 OS to 22.04 OS.

Thanks.

I need to confirm whether cpio is standalone executable or not

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cpio ?

Comment: @OcasoProtal I have gone through thins link it found around 6 diff packages. Thank you for information. But I just need information like will it supports backward and forward compatible. Say like 16.04 executable will work fine on 22.04 OS and vice-versa

Comment: You actully have two different questions. 1. Does `cpio` require external dependencies(does it have all its dependencies bundled in it)? No. 2.Is there a version of `cpio` that runs both on 16.04 and 22.04? The 16.04 version should be able to run on 22.04 because the only external dependency is glibc, and glibc is backward-compatible. Also note this question is not about programming and therefore is off-topic here.

Comment: You never want to share executables that the end user can install from their standard distro.

Comment: If I correctly remember, `cpio` is a nice tool, but portability was a problem when I tried to used it. In the end, I chosed to stick with tar + gz or bz because it is a much more portable format.

Comment: Unless you are sharing all static-linked executables in your package, solving the cpio issue won't take you anywhere, as you soon discover other incompatibilities